# How to do word-wrap for data using react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme for displaying table from server response. But for column data with long length, its showing ellipsis. I am not finding a way for wrapping it, so that full data is displayed.

In the doc, they have mentioned `style` prop, but I am not able to figure it out. I tried below, but it did not work.

```
<ReactTable
    data={respDataArr}
    columns={columns}
    style={{overflow:'wrap'}}
/>
```

Can someone suggest please what change should I do?

Comment: is answered here.. https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/578

Comment: Thanks @Panther, I tried `Cell: props => <div className=''>{props.value}</div>` but it did not work. Its not showing ellipsis, but cell width has not increased and the data rather goes hiding from the right edge.

Comment: u may try some css for ur div.. like word-break: all and width as 100%

Answer (score 52):

You'll want to use the css property `white-space: unset;`

find the column you want to have wrap text and add the following as a property of the column

```
// Example Column definition
{
    Header: 'header', 
    accessor: 'data1',
    style: { 'whiteSpace': 'unset' } //Add this line to the column definition
}
```

Alternatively you can add a class that targets `.ReactTable .rt-td` directly in your css/sass/scss

Edited: *Added example column definition to make it clearer, updated to new react-table api*

Comment: it works, although at columns points I had to declare in CSS white-space: normal.

Comment: Works, but I had to set whiteSpace instead of 'white-space', Bests

Comment: Thanks @José, Updated the answer

Answer (score 12):

To further make the answer clearer according to Steffan:

This is my column definition :

```
   const responsesData = [{..}, {..} .... etc ..];
   const columsDefnSamplesQsReactTable = [{
        Header: 'Question Code',
        accessor: 'Id'
    }, {
        Header: 'Question Text',
        accessor: 'QuestionText',
        style: { 'white-space': 'unset' } // allow for words wrap inside only this cell
    }];

    <ReactTable data={responsesData} columns= columsDefnSamplesQsReactTable } 
     defaultPageSize={3} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order to get this to work for me I had to use this sytnax:

```
style: { 'whiteSpace': 'unset' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now simply add the property `wrap: true` to the column properties:

```
{
  name: title,
  selector: property, 
  sortable: true, 
  wrap: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const columsDefnSamplesQsReactTable = [
  {
    Header: "Question Code",
    accessor: "Id",
  },
  {
    Header: "Question Text",
    accessor: "QuestionText",
    style: { overflowWrap: "break-word" }, // allow for words wrap inside this cell
  },
];
```